# onload div/modal window with "please wait"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big form, with many list boxes that are feeded by an jQuery plugin, jCombo.

```
$("select#arhpcnDetinator").jCombo("services/detinatori.php", { 
       initial_text: "Selecteaza valoarea",
       selected_value: $("input#arhpcndetinatorID").val()
});
```

The problem: because are many objects in form, feeded by jQuery&jSON, have some latency on loading. DOM is loading instantly, but listbox are populated much slowly (3-4sec).  So I need show an autoclosing loading div ("Please wait...). I tryed many variants  but are loaded after listboxes are populated. Also I find a simple solution using prototype, but are incompatible with jQuery :(.
If someone can figure a solution, I'll appreciate that. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy :)

I created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnp3v/) for you

Comment: :)  OMG, OMG :)) Where are you? You deserve a beer !

Comment: Me again. Finally I simplify your solution to

$(window).load(function(){ 
    $("#wait-please").remove();
});

but is working just at refresh(F5). 
When page is first loaded from a link, the div #wait-please does not apear.

Comment: Solved with different approach (fadeID - fadeOut)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this JCombo plugin but maybe it has a callback function parameter. If it does, on DOM ready show "Please wait" annd in the callback function the "Please wait" window.

Comment: yes, but how initialize "please wait" object before other. All is loading in $(document).ready(function() {...}); Just put it first is enogh? I'll try. Thank you for quick answer.